# Program that prints the smallest element greater than x in a given unsorted array A[]

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

I have to a program using recursion whose input is an array A of positive numbers and a positive number x. The program should print the smallest element of A that is greater than x. If such an element does not exist, the program should print −1. For
example, if A = [1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 5] and x = 3 then the program should print 5.

I have solved this program by conventional method without using recursion as follows:

```
FindNum(A[ ], x) {
result = -1;
for (i = 0; i < len(A[ ]); i++) {
if (A[i] > x AND (result > A[i] OR result == -1)) {
result = A[i];
}
}
print (result);
}
```

I have implemented this pseudo code in python accordingly and it works fine. Now I must do it using recursion. I have tried to do it but I am not so sure how to implement it correctly:

```
FindNum(A [ ], x) {
i = len(A[]) - 1;
result = -1;
while (i > 0 {
if (A[i] > x AND (result > A[i] OR result == -1)) {
result = A[i];
i--;
}
FindNum(A[i], x);
}
print result;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to place `;` if you're coding in python. Also, see the code indentation.Are you sure you have coded in python? Even the function declaration isn't proper.

Comment: This is pseudo code. I wrote in python separately to test the code which worked fine for the non-recursive solution. I am doing programming exercises. I do not have to type in specific language just need to get the program logic correct in the pseudocode. Sorry for the confusion in the question.

Comment: This code is rather unreadable without proper indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python recursive function with simple conditions (without one-liners). It finds result for list tail, then tries to improve it with current element

```
def mingreater(A, x):
    if 0 == len(A):
        return -1
    result = mingreater(A[1:], x)
    if result > 0:
        if A[0] > x:
            return min(result, A[0])
    else:
        if A[0] > x:
            return A[0]
    return result
```

Without Python-specific slices:

```
def mingreater(A, x, idx):
    if idx == len(A):
        return -1
    result = mingreater(A, x, idx + 1)
    if result > 0:
        if A[idx] > x:
            return min(result, A[idx])
    else:
        if A[idx] > x:
            return A[idx]
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Will it be possible to get a general pseudo code for the problem, as I am not an expert in python to understand the full code.

Comment: But..  It was you mentioned Python :). Yes, it is possible - introduce argument idx to mark index of tail start of array/list to treat, make recursive call with idx+1, use A[idx] instead of A[0]